# How much scrap can a Scrap Crew scrap if a Scrap Crew could scrap scrap?

Tags: mad-max

How does the Scrap Crew stronghold project work? What is its rate of scrap generation when I am online/offline? When does the amount sync to my game and is there anything I can do to affect the rate?

Comment: Nominated for: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2187/the-memes-of-arqade-and-its-chat

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Based on my experience and from what I've seen other users post elsewhere. It seems that each active scrap crew gives you roughly 7-11 scrap/hour, and seems to peak at 500 scrap per crew. There is no way to increase the rate at which each crew collects. So, if you want a rough equation it comes down to:

---

x = number of crews (each stronghold may have a crew)

y = number of hours since you stopped playing

**x*y*10 = amount of scrap (capping out at 500 scrap per crew)**.

---

You will get the scraps when you start the game again with an online connection.

So the most you would be able to get, assuming you have a scrap crew at all four strongholds, is ***2,000 scrap after roughly 50 hours.***

Or in better terms:

***A scrap crew would scrap as much scrap as a scrap crew could scrap if a scrap crew could scrap scrap.***

Comment: So, in short: min(crews * hours * 10, crews * 500)